# Copy and Pasting Values based on Column Header

Tags: excel, vba

Having a bit of trouble with some code. I basically want to copy and paste values based on the column header cell (High Level Status) so that i get rid of the formulas present.
Code is below

```
 With ActiveWorkbook
    With Worksheets(1)
    For i = 20 To 1 Step -1
            If cells(1, i) = "High Level Status" Then
            .cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Copy
            .cells(1, i).EntireColumn.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
    Next i
            End With
    End With
```

when I run the code it runs with no error messages yet dosnt perform as asked. Any ideas why?

Comment: You aren't actually referring to `With ActiveWorkbook` and `With Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Were you anticipating this code to loop?

Comment: I think you need to prefix with . When using the With/End. It should read .worksheets(1) and .cells(1,I)

Comment: verified solution . thanks @ChrisKiniry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assign Values

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub assignValuesQF()
    Dim j As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For j = 20 To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(1, j) = "High Level Status" Then
                With .Columns(j)
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

**More Efficient**

```
Sub assignValues()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 20 To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(1, j).Value = "High Level Status" Then
                Dim LastRow As Long
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
                ' No need to paste values for header (Resize, Offset).
                With .Cells(1, j).Resize(LastRow - 1).Offset(1)
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                Exit For ' you have found it, no need to loop anymore.
            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```